# Android Firebase read ArrayList object from database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I uploaded an ArrayList of objects in my firebase database with setValue,

It was stored this way:[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER8vH.png)

And now I'm wondering if I could retrieve this ArrayList from the database to use the information in it to populate a listview.

```
public class Alarm {

    private String alarm_time;
    private String alarm_ampm;
    private String alarm_days;

    public void setAlarm_time(String time) {
        alarm_time = time;
    }

    public void setAlarm_ampm(String ampm) {
        alarm_ampm = ampm;
    }

    public void setAlarm_days(String days) {
        alarm_days = days;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return this.alarm_time;
    }

    public String getAmpm() {
        return this.alarm_ampm;
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return this.alarm_days;
    }
}
```

This is what an Alarm looks like, and the Alarms are stored in the ArrayList that I uploaded to the database.

Is there a way to retrieve an ArrayList directly from firebase database? Or is there any library that might help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void getAlarmLlist() {
        final List<Alarm> alarmList=new ArrayList();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("alarm_list");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Alarm alarm= postSnapshot.getValue(Alarm.class);
                        alarmList.add(alarm);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error: ", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!